# Clojure Leiningen compile error with multiple projects - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, clojure, compilation, leiningen

I have a clojure library rotary, which is used by my own project api. I have a second project called pipeline, which uses api, and does not touch rotary directly.

I have tried clearing my `.lein` folder, and always use lein clean before compiling.

What I see:

1. Rotary compiles and installs correctly. I can use it from both repl
   and standalone jars.
2. Api compiles and installs correctly. Functions that use rotary work from repl and standalone jars.

If I comment out the rotary library from api, then the pipeline project, which uses api, compiles fine, and all non-rotary functionality works.  This all makes sense to me.

However, when I leave rotary in api, after I lein install it, then the pipeline project errors on compile.

I am at an extreme loss on why api would work with rotary, while pipeline errors out, especially when I can narrow it down to rotary through commenting it out. If there were a problem with the rotary code, then I would expect rotary / api to fail to compile, especially as pipeline doesn't use rotary directly.

Attached is the error, taken from the pipeline project `lein compile` command:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, compiling:(channel.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3387)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7035)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7025)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7097)
at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:387)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:619)
at pipeline.core$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(core.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3382)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7035)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7025)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7097)
at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:387)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
at clojure.core$compile$fn__4895.invoke(core.clj:5426)
at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5425)
at user$eval7.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6477)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2797)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:297)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:316)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:349)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
at api.db.dynamo$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(dynamo.clj:1)
at api.db.dynamo__init.load(Unknown Source)
at api.db.dynamo__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
at api.db.core$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(core.clj:1)
at api.db.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
at api.db.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
at api.thing$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(thing.clj:1)
at api.thing__init.load(Unknown Source)
at api.thing__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
at pipeline.jobs.channel$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(channel.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3382)
... 48 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchGetItemResult
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at rotary.client__init.__init0(Unknown Source)
at rotary.client__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 129 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens for me when I attempt to load multiple versions of a dependency because two of my dependencies depend in turn on the same library with different versions. You can check for this by running:

```
lein deps :tree
```

then look for the duplicated dependency and ad an `exclude` statement to one of the dependencies so there is only one dependency attempting to fill the requirement.

```
[org.jclouds.driver/jclouds-slf4j "1.5.5"                  
  :exclusions [org.slf4j/slf4j-api]]
```

I have also seen this with projects that expect you to provide a library that fills a particular interface and I use the wrong version. For instance using pallet with the wrong version of jClouds, though this is much less common than overlapping dependencies.
If it's none of these then it is very likely that someone in the #clojure irc channel on freenode.net will be able to walk you through debugging it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could you point out what a duplicated dependency would look like?

I might have found the issue, in the API and rotary project, I have the following dependency:

    [rotary "0.4.3"]
   [com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk "1.5.8"]

and in the pipeline, rotary doesn't call java-sdk:

     [com.cemerick/bandalore "0.0.3"]
   [com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk "1.3.21.1"]

So it seems a different projectowever how can I let them both use different versions of java? do I have to patch bandalore to use latest version?

Comment: Using multiple projects that demand different versions is really tricky, and fortunately almost always unnecessary. First try adding an exclusion for [com.cemerick/bandalore "0.0.3"] :exclusions [com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk "1.3.21.1"]. In most cases I have had this fix it.

Comment: To answer your above comment's question, a duplicated dependency looks just like that.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm looking into the documentation, however wouldn't this mean I have to patch bandalore to work with 1.5.8 if I exclude it as a dep?

So this *might* work if bandalore can work with 1.5.8 without patching, but wouldn't this break otherwise and require a way to specify two versions of the aws-java-sdk for each dependency?

Comment: Yes, you understand this correctly. Some refer to this as "dependency hell" and it can be really frustrating. There are ways to work around it using class loaders, though it's not for the feint of heart ;-)